# Separating Date to new column

Tags: r

I have data looks like this.

```
ID | Date| Status
1 | 3/2 | start
1 | 4/3 | end
```

From here, I want to bring these two rows into one by creating new column 'StartDate' and 'EndDate'.

```
ID |StartDate|EndDate
1| 3/2| 4/3
```

Comment: Search for reshape long to wide. Tons of posts on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The data:

```
> df
   id date Status
 1  1  2/3  Start
 2  1  4/3    End
```

Like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- spread(df, Status, date)
```

Output:

```
> df2
  id End Start
1  1 4/3   2/3
```

I used different numbers as dates

Comment: Thanks for replying! However, I got an Error:

Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows

I checked the data but there is no duplicated identifiers

Comment: @Marie: I need to look at a larger instance of the data. Can you edit your post and add a larger sample?